# How flexible are modern HDL Synthesis tools in terms of output primitives?

Tags: hdl

As a firmware guy I'm fascinated with porting tools like GCC to support arbitrary weird processors, which nowadays can be manifested on FPGAs with relative ease. I'm curious whether something equivalent exists in the hardware / HDL world.
My limited understanding of how FPGA tools work is that they generate a netlist which connects a bunch of "primitive" components, usually whatever is available in the target device. My question is, are there any examples of creating a new target for this generated output? If I wanted to implement a design using only DIP EEPROM and D flip flop chips, could I tell an HDL tool to generate an output using those components? I guess my ideal answer would be "Here's a big book on how these tools work and how to extend them."

Comment: Google "technology mapping".

Comment: Regarding "Here's a big book on how these tools work and how to extend them." - here is a nice [course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/vlsi-cad-logic) which will cover the basics :)

Comment: Also note, that synthesis tools are mostly proprietary, as well as the technology being used in the actual FPGAs. There are *very few* open-source tools, such as Yosys, which are documented to the best extent they can, but each "target" addition is based mostly on much of reverse-engineering work, rather than any well-established process.

Comment: @EugeneSh. while that's true, one takeaway is that the tools used for technology mapping just actually take descriptive files of the technologies they map to – it's not easy to generate these, but if you have them, there's nothing really stopping you from using your mapper instead of for FPGA cells for, say, arrays of 7400 series logic ICs. [cough](http://pepijndevos.nl/2019/07/18/vhdl-to-pcb.html)

Comment: @MarcusMüller: That link is very cool, even if it is of limited practical value. If I ever get enough free time, I'm going to play around with that! I have this vague idea about building a small CPU using just NOR gates made from discrete transistors, and that would be an educational way of going about it.